# Как достать значение переменной из БД php wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, база-данных, переменные

Здраствуйте! Использую тему motors на wordpress. Мне вставить переменные в тайтл бокс. Там уже есть переменные марки авто и модель. Нужно вставить год выпуска (ca-year), Тип горючего (fuel) и коробку передач (transmission). Как это сделать?

Код, где уже вставлены марка и модель и нужно вставить другие переменные:

```
$title = get_the_title( $post_id );
$title .= /* Переменные */ ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно знать где именно хранится значение ваших полей, а также их имя. Скорей всего они лежат в таблице postmeta. Тогда это будет выглядит примерно вот так

```
$title = get_the_title( $post_id );
$title .= get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ca-year', true);
$title .= get_post_meta( $post_id, 'fuel', true);
...
```

Подробней про эту функцию можно прочесть вот здесь https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_meta

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили. Если вам не сложно, можете подсказать, как расшифровать кириллицу. У меня горючее и коробка передач выводятся, как: %D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: решил проблему вот так `$title .= urldecode(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'transmission', true));`. Спасибо за функцию get_post_meta, я бы еще долго над этим тупил